# Сервер Apache не запускается

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, intellij-idea, tomcat, localhost

Я хочу запустить сервер, но получаю ошибку:

```
Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099.
And in console: /home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/bin/catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/devnull/.IntelliJIdea2016.2/system/tomcat/Unnamed_lovelystickers
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       
/home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/devnull/Software/idea-IU-162.2228.15/plugins/apache-tomcat-8.0.38/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Disconnected from server
```

Ubuntu linux 16.04/intellij idea

Comment: `reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099` наверное, в этом дело.

Comment: Пробовал разные порты - не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно глупая ошибка, оказывается томкат не особо дружит с jdk из стандартного репозитория. Я скачал jdk с oracle.com и подключил к intellij, все заработало:)